# how to get $stmt to return from a class function in mysqli

Tags: php, function, class, mysqli

My question is that I use mysqli in class function. I want to be able to return $stmt and use it, so that I can separate a lot of php from my html.

Here is my first bit of code, which is in the class of ticket

```
public function listTickets(){
    $query = "SELECT `subject` FROM `tickets` WHERE `test_id`=?";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$_SESSION['data']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($subject);
    return $stmt;
}
```

Then I call it like this from another file, but of course this does not work, because for some reason my class function is not returning a binded $stmt. However there is no error.

```
$stmt=$ticket->listTickets();
while($stmt->fetch())
{
    echo '<pre>'.$subject.'</pre>';
}
```

However if I bind it after returning it works, which is annoying because I have already binded it in my function.

```
$stmt=$ticket->listTickets();   
$stmt->bind_result($subject);
while($stmt->fetch())
{
    echo '<pre>'.$subject.'</pre>';
}
```

So binding after returning works, but I would rather returned the binded $stmt so I can have less code cluttering up my html.

I know there are various ways of returning output from a mysqli call like loading it into arrays and stuff, but I was trying to do it with as less code as possible (and please nobody suggest pdo.)

So my question is how do I return a binded $stmt from my function without having to bind it after returning?

Ok going to add a little more. My mysqli is working correctly as when I do this inside the function it works ok

```
while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo '<pre>'.$subject.'</pre>';
        }
```

Comment: As you dont have a `$data` variable in the method I would expect it to be an error in the `prepare()`

Comment: The reason there are no errors is you are not looking for any. Test the result of the `prepare` and `execute`

Comment: Looks like that query will only return one result. bind and fetch it and then just return the value

Comment: If I bind and fetch before returning that means copying the output into an array of some sort as there is more than one item, which is what I was trying to avoid. I wanted to fetch outside of my class function with as little code as possible

Comment: Ryan $subject does not need to be passed in as it is a variable to bind data from the mysql table. $subject is taken from the table. Bear in mind I have already said the query actually works. It is only the returning part that doesn't

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seeing as nobody could give me a satisfactory answer I painstakenly found my own answer. It was nothing to do with scope.

Actually I have two answers and they both work. In the new answer I don't have to bind my variables, because I am using either fetch_assoc, or fetch_object.

So here is my answer

```
public function listTickets(){
    $query = "SELECT `subject` FROM `tickets` WHERE `test_id`=?";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$_SESSION['data']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    return $result;
    //Notice I am not binding at all, and instead of returning $stmt, I am returning $result.
}
```

Ok the code above is the same for both answers, but in my other file I can do it two different ways.
Here is the first way, which outputs an object

```
$result=$ticket->listTickets();
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    echo $row->subject;
}
```

And here is the second way, which outputs an associative array

```
$result=$ticket->listTickets();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['subject'];
}
```

The difference is that the first one uses an object and the second one uses an associative array.

It took me many hours to work this out, but I am happy I actually worked it out on my own.

Comment: Such a function, for sake of a *real* separation between php and html, should return an array with data, without any reference to a database driver.

Comment: I could return an array quite easily, but I didn't see the need. The code to loop an array is about the same as the code to loop through the fetch object or assoicated array. Obviously to populate an array would take more memory than not populating an array and just reading it from the fetch object

Comment: This statement of yours (talking of memory occupied by a dozen of records) is a sure proof that your other assumptions on the performance are just imaginary issues unrelated to any real life stuff. Pity, these assumptions lead to real architectural problems.

Comment: You are making assumptions about something you have no idea about. You do not know how many records I will be using, or in what way I am going to use it. Did I say it was going to be a dozen records? I thought this was a professional site. Are you just going to follow my posts and keep voting me down just for the hell of it? I.The answer is correct because it works for me. I am very sorry you got upset because I voted you down on that other question, but you gave incorrect information. I thought this site was supposed to be professional not personal.

Answer (score 0):

$subject is not defined in the listTickets() method. Variables inside the method scope is not visible outside of the method. I think the last code you wrote is the best approach.

Comment: Neither is `$data` so the query might be failing in the prepare

Comment: No sorry $data is not a problem, It is a SESSION variable, but I replaced the variable name because it did not make sense in this demonstrateion. Will change that to avoid confusion.

Comment: I understand scope, but what I thought was this. If $subject is being binded to $stmt, I thought if I returned $stmt it would still be binded to it.

Comment: Ok is there a better method for returning my output to my other file? I thought doing it this way instead of sticking it all in an array would save code, and memory you see.